# Shift date from remote source with local

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Received data from remote resource

Comment: Why are you *formatting* the current time rather than *parsing* the time you've been given? That would be a much cleaner way to go, IMO. Now, is the time zone *always* Etc/GMT? That would make things simple...

Answer (score 2):

## a String != a Date-Time

You are conflating date-time values with their formatted String representation. You need to parse the input string into a date-time object. Then generate another date-time object to represent "now". Compare the two objects by calling the `isBefore` or `isAfter` method.

Similarly, do not confuse the formatted String `$12.34` with a number. How would you compare that to another number? You would parse the input string into a number object, perform your business logic, and lastly generate a String representation of the result for display to the user. Ditto for date-time work.

Do not worry about shifting time zones. Any pair of `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` may be compared via `isBefore` or `isAfter` regardless of time zone.

I'll not show any code as this Question is really a duplicate of hundreds of other Questions. Please search StackOverflow to learn much more. Search for words "java date parse" and "java date compare". Focus on Answers involving "java.time" or "Java 8".

Answer (score 2):

Your format string doesn't match your sample input.  To match the input, your format string should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"`

As @JonSkeet and @BasilBourque suggest, you should parse an `Instant` or a `ZonedDateTime` from the input string.  I don't see the question of parsing an `Instant` well-addressed on SO, so here's how you do it:

```
// may want to declare and maintain this elsewhere
DateTimeFormatter remoteFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV");

Instant remote = remoteFormat.parse(s, Instant::from); 

boolean remoteInThePast = Instant.now().isAfter(remote);
```